# Do I need server to access json value

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, getjson

I have a html file (somename.html) and json file(data.json). When i open the html file directly(i.e by using open with google chrome) I dont get any response. but when i open it using localhost(i.e localhost/somename.html), I get the response from the json file. Could some one explain me what is happening? I am using the following code. Do i need a server or for this access ? I want to have my html file on client side and json files on server. How could this be done? Here is my code.

**In the html file**

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/job/data.json', function(data) {



   $("#id1").val(data.users[0].a);
   $("#id2").val(data.users[0].b);
   $("#id3").val(data.users[0].c);
   $("#id4").val(data.users[0].d);




   });
```

**here is my data.json file**

```
{"users":[
    {
        "a":"50",
        "b":"0",
        "c":"10",
        "d":"54";
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is a pre-configured hostname that points to the current local system.. In case you are using this online, the webserver will look on its own system for the file, however most webservers do not point the requests for localhost to a certain web folder.

For more information about localhost, check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

As to the solution, you will either have to use a relative path, eg: /data.json and publish the file in your public path of your website. Or you can use an absolute path that points to the full url, eg: http://yourdomain.com/data.json. More on this here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm

Loading information from your home pc is possible (not advisable) by loading the file directly from your IP (or domain if you have DNS set up properly). Make sure the request to your IP can be routed to your machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

In getJson simply give a path to your .json file!